# How to use multidimensional constant array in for iterator block in matlab/simulink?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, simulink

I have an array (300x6) and I want to use it for this block in simulink. But I have a problem. How can I use "for iterator" block to take the q(i,:), q(i+1,:) , q(i+2,:) ... elements respectively? Or is there any other way to do this idea? Thanks.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the rows?  Are you trying to use a different row at successive simulation time steps?  If so, that's not what the "for iterator" in Simulink is used for.  Using the "for iterator" in your model would make q, qd and qdd take the values from the last row only (after doing the calculation for all the other rows and then throwing the results away).

Comment: @Phil Goddard  Yes I am trying to use a different row at successive simulation time steps. By using for iterator block I cant do this , so how can I do dou you know?

Comment: You want to use a From Workspace or an Inport block to import the data. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-signal-data-in-simulink.html for a description of different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, [`for`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/for.html) iterates over matrix *columns*. So you can just transpose to iterate over rows:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; %// example matrix
for v = A.'
    v = v.'; %// v will be [1 2 3], then [4 5 6] etc
    %// Do stuff with v
end
```

I'm not into Simulink but I guess you can adapt this to that environment.

Comment: How can I do in block diagram ? @Luis Mendo

Comment: @DMD In Simulink you can edit a block's contents and put Matlab code there, right? I don't use Simulink, I can't tell you much more about that, sorry